# How to programmatically disable ComboBox items which satisfy condition

Tags: c#, wpf

In a ComboBox there are some items which have to be enabled and some which have to be disabled (and visible).

At first the ComboBox ItemsSource is set:

```
comboBoxMachine.ItemsSource = machineList;
```

where comboBoxMachine is a `ComboBox` and machineList is a `List<Machine>` (`Machine` is a custom object)

Later a condition for each machine from the list has to be checked and in case it is fulfilled the appropriate item from the ComboBox has to be disabled.

Below is the combination of code/pseudocode of the logic:

```
private void modifyMachineComboBoxItems()
    {
        foreach (Machine mch in machineList)
        {
            if (constructionSiteSchedule.ReservationMachinePeriods.Count(x => x.MachineId == mch.Id) > 0) //if this condition is fulfilled, it should be not possible to select the machine from the comboBoxMachine
            {
                int currentPosition = machineList.IndexOf(mch);
                disable the element from the comboBoxMachine at position currentPosition;
            }
        }
    }
```

What I haven't figured out so far is how to disable the element from the ComboBox at given position so I would be very thankful if anyone could modify the code above such that the ComboBox items for machines that satisfy the condition are disabled.

Comment: Seems like something similar has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003318/wpf-how-to-disable-combobox-items

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the item from the list? or else you need to extend a ComboBoxItem and allow to set it to a disabled state.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it this way? Because I'm not sure doing that is a good UI design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just have boolean property on your machine that corresponds to whether the item is enabled, in your `ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle` you can bind `IsEnabled` to that property, then when you want to disable the item just set the property on the machine to false.

---

Alternatively you could use the [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) (which you really should not):

```
var item = comboBoxMachine.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(currentPosition) as ComboBoxItem;
item.IsEnabled = false;
```

*(You do not need to get the position first by the way as there also is a [`ContainerFromItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem.aspx) method, also see the [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723726/how-to-programmatically-disable-combobox-items-which-satisfy-condition/6723965#comment15952596_6723965))*

Comment: It may also be wise to warn about accessing the `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex()` (or *.ContainerFromItem()*) before the Generator has finished generating the containers. If you try to access them before it's complete, you'll receive an Exception. Refer to the [`Status` / `StatusChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) Property / Event for more information.